# python paho-mqtt loops & persistan connection to broker

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi, mqtt, paho

I've written some python3 code to do the following in sequence;

1. check if internet up
2. if internet up connect to MQTT broker
3. publish message to pub_topic every 30mins
4. and loop to step one & repeat

Also, I'd like the MQTT connection to be persistent so that incoming messages can be received.

What's happening is that after a few iterations the MQTT connection drops out and eventually the programme crashes.

Below is my while loop code snippet;

```
while True:
        try:
                if not internet_up():
                        time.sleep(20)

                client = mqtt.Client()
                client.on_connect = on_connect
                client.on_message = on_message
                client.connect(broker, 1883, 60)
                client.loop_start()


                if internet_up():
                        print(read_temp())
                        client.publish(pub_topic, read_temp())
                        time.sleep(60*30)


        except Exception as err:
                logging.info(err)
                pass
```

A. Is there an obvious error here?

B. I don't feel this is optimal, how could this be made more efficient, pyhonic or corrected?

C. Also, what is the difference between `loop_start()` & `loop_forever()` ? I've read the documentation and it's not obvious to me.

Comment: `loop_start` starts a background thread to run the event loop, `loop_forever` blocks running the event loop on the current thread

Comment: Dodgy logic: What if during a  time.sleep(60*30)  the internet goes down long enough to break the broker connection but then comes back up before the 30 minutes is up - then your code would see 'great the internet is up at this instant so it must have been OK for the last 30 minutes' and assume the connection is still present and try to publish the reading when the broker connection isn't there. Better to hook into the on_disconnect() and use that to break out of your 'publishing every 30 minutes' loop. Or maybe always doing a client.reconnect() before the client.publish() would work, not sure

Comment: @barny thanks for your comment. I'm by no means an expert here, could you possibly add the on_connect() and client.reconnect() code you mentioned? I assumed that the combination of the loop_start() and the client.connect() would keep the MQTT connection to the broker up but it seems not. The Paho documentation isn't exactly lay friendly.

Comment: @hardillb thanks for your comment. Could you explain the event loop please? I find the documentation difficult to understand.

Comment: The loop_start() means your client will try to keep the connection active by sending the background keep-awake messages, and checking they are received from the broker, but it doesn't restore the connection if it is broken, that's up to your client code. If you provide an on_disconnect function it will be called, I guess for you this needs to provide code to at least set a flag to record that the client has disconnected so that your 30 minute sleep loop knows it has to go back to the connecting steps.

Comment: Best practice is to call connect, then loop start or loop forever, as noted in countless examples via google and even on github.

Answer (score 1):

Building off of barny's comment, I suspect the problem here is that you are repeatedly calling client.loop_start() without ever calling client.loop_stop() or client.disconnect().

To test this I wrote a test script using the mosquitto test server:

```
from time import sleep

import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt


def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
   client.subscribe('$SYS/broker/load/messages/received/1min')


def messages_received(client, userdata, message):
   print(message.payload)


while True:
   client = mqtt.Client()
   client.loop_start()
   client.message_callback_add('$SYS/broker/load/messages/received/1min', messages_received)
   client.on_connect = on_connect
   client.connect("test.mosquitto.org", 1883, 60)
   sleep(13)
```

This script failed within a few minutes. However, if I changed the last section to include client.loop_stop() and client.disconnect() like this:

```
while True:
  client = mqtt.Client()
  client.loop_start()
  client.message_callback_add('$SYS/broker/load/messages/received/1min', messages_received)
  client.on_connect = on_connect
  client.connect("test.mosquitto.org", 1883, 60)
  sleep(3)
  client.disconnect()
  client.loop_stop()
  sleep(10)
```

It ran indefinitely. I'm new to both python and paho, so there may be another issue here... also I only tested this with test.mosquitto.org so there may be broker specific issues... but to make your existing code work I would try at least adding client.loop_stop inside your loop.

However, since you want the connection to be persistent, you might want to consider using client.loop_forever() and placing your while loop into an on_connect callback or something similar to that.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Calling loop start before connect, has some known and documented issues, as documented on github issue list for the client.